# Mailgun: 'from' parameter is not a valid address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, actionmailer, mailgun

I am using [Mailgun](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby) to send my [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) confirmation emails. But I get the following error:

```
Mailgun::CommunicationError: 400 Bad Request: 'from' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation
```

[Full logs](https://gist.github.com/jonhue/24b5c79fca8f76d70fae8115d260a825)

What does this mean. Do I need to configure the senders email address with MailGun before I can use it?

Comment: Did you check the documentation as claimed in the error?

Comment: @Зелёный I looked at the documentation but did not found an article corresponding to my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Mailgun started checking "From" address more strictly. Here's an example of a recent [fix in Phabricator](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/commit/836819a0e7cac3b97b621e32e2d735a1e49d6dff) for this error:

> We are submitting `epriestley (Evan Priestley) <noreply@meta.phacility.com>`, but should be submitting `"epriestley (Evan Priestley)" <noreply@meta.phacility.com>`.